# warning: passing argument 1 of ... makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c++, enums

I have a enum like this:

```
enum PROCESS_TYPE
{
    PRI_PROC = 0,
    BG_PROC  = 64,
    INT_PROC = 128,
    TI_PROC  = 256,
    PHANTOM  = 512,
    BLOCK    = 1024,
    ZOOMBIE  = 2048,
    ILLEGAL  = 4096
};
```

I have a function called `create_process` which has one of the argument as a type of `PROCESS_TYPE` like this:

```
create_process(enum PROCESS_TYPE proc_type, const char *name, ...);
```

When I use the create_process function in this way:

```
create_process(BG_PROC, "server" ...);
```

I got error `passing argument 1 of 'create_process' makes pointer from integer without a cast`. How to solve this? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:for the second argument, it's a const char, but it also reports the error of `passing argument 2 of 'create_process' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: Are you using two programming languages at the same time?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I'm new to c/c++, I'm writing c++.

Comment: Hi, all, I added a edit, even for const char, it reports the same error, what might be the reason?

Comment: Your code compiles for me. Is `BG_PROC` defined somewhere else? Try changing it to `DIFFERENT_BG_PROC`, just to see what happens.

Comment: in C++ you don't need `enum` in the declaration `create_process(enum PROCESS_TYPE proc_type, const char *name, ...);`

Comment: What compiler are you using? what extension for the file? please add to the question the complete compilation command u are using.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Hi, my file is a `.c` file, but the library of the function `create_process` is a `.cc` file, should this be the reason?

Comment: @sramij the extension of my file is `.c`

Comment: @sramij my compiler is `gcc`.

Comment: Here we have the problem. C and C++ are not interoperable out of the box. Also, you can not simply compile C++ code as C or vice versa. You said you write in C++, now you say you save it as a C file and compile it with a C compiler (gcc is a C compiler, g++ is a C++ compiler, both are part of the GCC (GNU compiler collection)).

Comment: @leemes exactly as what you said, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your function call as `create_process(BG_PROC, "server");` instead of `create_process(BG_PROC, "server" ...);`. For me this following code is working fine..

```
 enum PROCESS_TYPE {
    PRI_PROC = 0,
    BG_PROC  = 64,
    INT_PROC = 128,
    TI_PROC  = 256,
    PHANTOM  = 512,
    BLOCK    = 1024,
    ZOOMBIE  = 2048,
    ILLEGAL  = 4096
   };

   void create_process(enum PROCESS_TYPE, const char *,...);

   int main() {
        create_process(BG_PROC, "server");
   }

   void create_process(enum PROCESS_TYPE proc_type, const char *name,...) {
     // ...
   }
```